# MessageBox.Show erro dialogresult

Tags: c#

Não sei o que eu fiz mas  da erro:

> Error 4   A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces;
>   'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon' is a type not a
>   namespace C:\Users\Guilherme\Documents\PainelX\PainelX\Form1.cs   25  7   PainelX

print do erro : http://prntscr.com/8dhnl8

```
public void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("mensagem", "titulo",  MessageBoxIcon.Warning, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O erro diz para olhar na linha 25. De certeza vai encontrar isso:

```
using System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon;
```

Isso não funciona porque [`MessageBoxIcon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.messageboxicon(v=vs.110).aspx) não é um namespace, é um `enum`.
Então basta importar o namespace que contém `MessageBoxIcon`.

```
using System.Windows.Forms
```